# Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderation

Stemming from this question on the webapps meta: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/moderator-nominations , I believe it's time to start nominating moderators. Copied as a template from the webapps meta:

> I hereby open up
>   this question for moderator
>   nominations.
>
> - Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's
>     profile so we can see their activity.
> - The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed
>     editing) the answer.
> - The top voted nominations can go forward to the vote.
> - The voting will be done on a separate question.
>
> Some guidelines (from Jeff's original
>   answer):
>
> 1. Must be a currently registered user in good standing
> 2. Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active,
>      consistent participation.
> 3. Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their
>      questions, answers, and comments.
> 4. Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community
>      members in everything they write.
> 5. They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t
>      the same as an obligation. It’s purely
>      voluntary!

More on the moderation nomination and selection process: [How to organize a formal moderator election on a beta SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site)

Of the nominees, the SE team will select 3 candidates a week after public beta starts.

Comment: This comment may result inflammatory, but I feel I should point out that (regardless who is right, if one of them is) both Aaronaught and Pulse fail a bit on points 3 and 4 with their quarrels.

Comment: It's not inflammatory, it's true.  I can only add that most of those quarrels have been on one very specific topic here on meta, not the main site, and that I don't think either of us would take unilateral actions contrary to the current community standard.  But by all respects, people should still take that history into account and vote for someone who's strong on *all* fronts.  My vote goes to Joe, if he wants the job.

Comment: The only discussion I'd really count as argumentative was the issue with language (for which I'm still trying to figure out if someone's already done it, or if there's good software out there so I can maintain and host a multi-lingual thesaurus.)  As for wanting the job -- I'd edit / tag / whatever stuff anyway.  I just don't want to the *only* person, as I might get bogged down for weeks at a time from my jobs, or be on travel where I don't have easy internet access.  But I'm passionate about food & learning, so I'd be willing to do what I can to help out.

Comment: And just from having done the moderation type stuff over the years on various things ... it helps to have more than just Americans ... because the Europeans and Aussies live in different time zones, they might be around when all of the Americans are sleeping and someone's being harrassing/etc.  I think JustRightMenus might be another possible candidate ... strong showing so far, even with starting a week after many of us.

Comment: @Joe, it's CW, so please edit your entry if you're accepting, and please nominate justrightmenus.

Comment: @Joe, it's also my understanding that you get access to special moderator tools to facilitate with the job, and while I'm not certain, I would guess there has to be more than one mod.

Comment: @Mike : it's hard to judge after just a week ... I'll nominate JustRightMenus when I get a better feel for (her?) ... I'll likely wait a few days, and try to read through (her?) comments / answers / etc.

Comment: @Joe, yeah, it is early. No pressure :-)

Comment: It's probably worth making sure the nominations cover the main timezones/locales when the site is active, too.

Comment: How many moderators are we looking for?

Comment: @Sam, these are just nominations. So as many as we want I suppose. I'm kind of playing this by ear, and will seek more input from webapps as guidance.

Comment: I believe that they end up choosing 3 moderators.

Comment: They choose 3 a week after public beta has started: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site

Comment: Which is the difference between a nominated moderator and someone that reached the reputation level for moderator tools?

Comment: As Rowland Shaw pointed, we should have moderators spawned on all time zones: so at least one in Central Europe (UTC+1), one in USA or Canada (UTC-7), one in Asia (UTC+9). This should hopefully cover all the 24-hours. What about adding the timezone (e.g UTC-8) to the nomination?

Comment: I don't think the timezones have much relevance. Some people work nights, some work days, some work 12 hour shifts, some work only 3-4 days a week, etc.

Answer (score 8):

[hobodave](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/60/hobodave) - accepted

Comment: Hey! Thanks guys. I accept.

Answer (score 8):

[JustRightMenus](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/364/justrightmenus) - accepted

Comment: Thanks, Dinah! As a stay-at-home mom of one, I should certainly have the time (thanks to baby's naps). Where can I find a description of a moderator's responsibilities?

Comment: @JustRightMenus: Here's an early description from Stack Overflow: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Answer (score 6):

[Sam Holder](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/210/sam-holder) - accepted

Comment: I can't promise to be available all the time, but I'm happy to help spread the load.

Answer (score 5):

[Mike Sherov](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/users/99/mike-sherov) :) - accepted

Comment: I'll accept the nomination.

Answer (score 4):

[Joe](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/67/joe) - accepted

Comment: I guess I accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[Aaronut](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/41/aaronut) - accepted

Comment: I'm sure that all of us on the list would do a good job, but if I somehow end up near the top, then sure, I'll accept.

Comment: Sorry but -1; I'll be quite blunt and say that I've down-voted because having seen the way you talk to people on here (not all the time, admittedly, but enough to bother me), I don't think you're suited to being a moderator

Comment: @Rob and @Aaronut: Before this turns into an epic comment thread... Do you think we should just keep our reasons for down-voting moderator nominations to ourselves? It's been avoided so far (I have 4 down votes and I don't care to know from who or why), and I think that might be for the best. There's just really no nice way to say it. Should we just let the votes speak for themselves?

Comment: @hobodave: If there is one thing I consistently believe in, it's that people should speak their minds. People *choose* to take offense at what others say. I choose *not* to take offense at these comments or any that follow. And I'll be blunt: I am *not* the "diplomatic" type, and if that is a hard requirement for being a mod, then I shouldn't be one. What I *am* offering is a ton of experience with the Stack Exchange system and the SO/MSO communities and a determination to make this site succeed. People should vote accordingly, and if they have something add, there's no reason to hide it.

Comment: @Aaronut: Fair enough, and I too agree with the people speaking their minds. I sure do. :) I was just trying to keep a heretofore positive thread, well...  positive. I'm not trying to squelch anyone.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>[Pulse](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/115/pulse)</strike>

Comment: Thanks to whoever put my name forward and thanks to whoever down-voted with out explanation. I'd really rather not be considered for a position as moderator, as I will have long periods of absence due to family commitments.

Comment: I nominated, and have now removed, you. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Thanks Mike, appreciated.